# Issue with :active and :hover states in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a problem with a css triggered overlay. The solution is working somewhat fine in Chrome, but has slight issues in Firefox and being wholly unusable in Internet Explorer.

In Firefox the problem is with :active. I have to hold down the mouse button for 1-2 to make the overlay stay, while in IE it doesn't show at all.

My HTML markup is thus:

```
<a href="#" id="aftermath" title="Mark Nielsen's 3D computer animation project devekoped at Aalborg Media College">                
                <article class="three columns"> 
                    <h1>
                        Aftermath
                    </h1>                                       
                    <img src="images/aftermath-video.jpg"  class="resize" alt="3D computer animation project by Mark Nielsen" />                    
                </article>                                
            </a>

<div class="infobox" id="aftermathinfo">
                <article>
                    <h1>
                        Aftermath
                    </h1>
                    <p class="truncate">This was the result of the "free project" from my stay at Media College Aalborg. Sebastian Baasch and I modelled this from a picture of an old army Jeep and did everything else ourselves. Besides modelling the Jeep and various objects in the landscape I also did all 2D graphics, editing and post effects.</p>
                    <p><a href="posts/aftermath-video.aspx" class="important-link" title="Mark Nielsen's 3D computer animation project devekoped at Aalborg Media College">See and read about the computer animation project here</a></p>
                    <p>&nbsp</p>
                    <p>&nbsp</p>
                    <p><a href="portfolio.aspx" title="Go look at Mark Nielsen's projects, including web page design, graphic design, programming and much more...">Close this window</a></p>
                </article>                
            </div>
```

and the corresponding CSS:

```css
.infobox {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    /*margin-left:-300px;*/
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0,.75);
    visibility:hidden;
    z-index:9999;
}

    .infobox article {
        text-align:center;
        margin-top:10%;
        padding:5%;
        padding-bottom:20%;
        width:100%;
        background-color:#292929;
        opacity:0.95;
    }

        .infobox article p {
            text-align:center;
        }

        .infobox article h1 {
            border:none;
            margin:2% 0;
            padding:0;
            font-size:1.8em;
        }

    .infobox a.important-link {
        font-size:1.5em;
        /*text-transform:uppercase;
        font-style:normal;*/
    }

.infobox:hover {
    visibility:visible;
}



#aftermath:active + #aftermathinfo {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Live version can be seen here: http://balder.ucn.dk/1020613/portfolio.aspx

Comment: I can't see any rules with `:active` pseudo element.

Comment: @matewka the last one.

Comment: Don't use the active state for make those elements `visible` the active state is only the moment between the press and release of the button.

Comment: @Danko yes, the idea is that on mousedown, the visible activates and the overlay's hover takes over before mouseup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this behavior is just not very well-defined and you're fighting with the browser's order of events.  (You also force a reload of the entire page when closing an overlay, which is suboptimal.)

Try using `:target` instead; it matches an element only if the fragment (`#foo` in the URL bar) is that element's id.  All you'd have to do is change your link to `<a href="#aftermathinfo">` (much better than `#` anyway) and your last selector to `#aftermathinfo:target`.  The "close" link can then just link to `#`, which will clear the fragment and disable `:target`.

Not sure how well it works in IE, alas.  Might only be 9+.  I see you're using HTML5 tags, so hopefully old IE isn't a problem.

Comment: I finally had time to try it out. It works beautifully so far. Didn't know about :target, that'll help me in the future.
Thank you very much!